# Lua Split string up and put output into a table

Tags: lua

I am trying using Lua to split a string up in the best way possible

The output I am trying to achieve is this.

```
"is"
"this"
"ents"
"cont"
"_"
etc
etc
```

Here is my code so far with no success

```
local variable1 = "this_is_the_string_contents"

local l = string.len(variable1)
local i = 0
local r = nil
local chunks = {} --table to store output in

while i < l do
r = math.random(1, l - i)

--if l - i > i then
--r = math.random(1, (l - i) / 2)
--else
--r = math.random(1, (l - i))
--end

print(string.sub(variable1, i, r))

chunks = string.sub(variable1, i, r)
i = i+r 

end
```

Comment: `to split a string up in the best way possible` - what does it mean "in the best way"?

Comment: why is `contents` split into `cont` and `ents`? are you looking for a max of 4 letters long, unless you hit a `_`?

Comment: @Nifim I was aiming to balence it out to be honnest it does not have to be 4 just for the entire string to be divided up into equal parts was my aim.

Comment: `chunks = string.sub(variable1, i, r)` sets the variable `chunks` to that, and turns it into a string rather than a table. You'd want `table.insert(chunks, string.sub(variable1, i, r)` for that. But what output do you get otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to divide the string into equal parts. The following will do precisely that as well as store it into the table.

```
local variable2 = "this_is_the_string_contents"

math.randomseed(os.time())
local l = #variable2
local i = 0
local r = math.random(1, l/2)
local chunks = {}

while i <= l+5 do
    print(variable2:sub(i, i+r))
    table.insert(chunks, variable2:sub(i,i+r))

    i = i+r+1
end
```

It's good habit to change the `math.randomseed` each time you run the script so you get more variance in random numbers. A quick breakdown, though.

`local r = math.random(1, l/2)`: You can change the 2 to be whatever you want, but what this does is prevent the script from assigning `#variable2` as the length, thus making it possible to get the variable as a single chunk.

`while i <= l+5 do`: I added the `+5` to account for some overage cases, just as a precaution.

`table.insert(chunks, variable2:sub(i, i+r))`: This is what you needed to insert into the table. Since we want an equal amount, you'll use `i+r` as the end sub.

`i = i+r+1`: You don't want repeat letters.

The end results show up as this:

```
Pass One:
this_is_the
_string_cont
ents   

Pass Two:
thi
s_is
_the
_str
ing_
cont
ents
```

And so forth. If this isn't what you're looking for, please advise and revise your question. If you're wanting to store the `_` separately and not part of the words, that's even easier, but the way you described it, you said evenly, so I went with keeping it in for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a random length for each string?

```
function GetRandomStringList(str)
    local str_table = {}
    while string.len(str)>0 do
        local str_chunk_size = math.random(1,string.len(str))
        table.insert(str_table,string.sub(str,1,str_chunk_size))
        str=string.sub(str,str_chunk_size+1)
    end
    return str_table
end

function DisplayStringList(name, str_table)
    print(name..":")
    for loop=1,#str_table do
        print(str_table[loop])
    end
    print("")
end

do
    local str = "this_is_the_string_contents"
    DisplayStringList("first", GetRandomStringList(str))
    DisplayStringList("second", GetRandomStringList(str))
    DisplayStringList("third", GetRandomStringList(str))
end
```

I simply loop whilst there are still characters existing in the string, randomly select a chunk size, insert that part of the string into a table, and then remove that part from the string. Repeat. When the string is empty, return table to caller for processing.

Output looks like:

```
first:
t
his_is_the_stri
ng_
content
s

second:
this_is_the_s
tring
_contents

third:
this_is_the_string_cont
ent
s
```